# How do I name a field in SQL script?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sapb1

I have this script:

```
 SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName,OITM.OnHand,
       DATEDIFF(day, MAX(RDR1.DocDate), GETDATE()) 
FROM OITM 
     JOIN RDR1
     ON OITM.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
WHERE OITM .OnHand > 0 
GROUP BY OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName, OITM.OnHand;
```

I would like this new "days_since_last_order" to be the name of the column when I link to SAP B1 to Excel. But at the moment it just shows as "column1". ["column1 issue example"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPtJU.png)

At what point in this script can I define it as "Days since last order"?

I tried writing a macro for it but it seems to work for the first refresh but not after, why would this be?

```
Sub New_SAP_Query()
'
' New_SAP_Query Macro
'

'
     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
   With Range("F5")
   .Value = Now()
   .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
   End With
   
    Range("B7").Select
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 83
    Range("F7:F1048576").Select
    Range("F1").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("F7").Select
    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days since last order"
    Range("C7").Select
    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

This is the worksheet [Macro issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsCzm.png).

My background is accounting not computer science FYI. I have tried to make this as clear as possible and hope it is a simple fix.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(day, MAX(RDR1.DocDate), GETDATE()) AS days_since_last_order`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as keyword

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName,OITM.OnHand,
   DATEDIFF(day, MAX(RDR1.DocDate), GETDATE()) as new_column_name FROM OITM JOIN RDR1 ON OITM.ItemCode =RDR1.ItemCode WHERE OITM.OnHand > 0 GROUP BY OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName,OITM.OnHand;
```